# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style') at showMenu & at HTMLElement.onclick. How do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am getting this error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')  at showMenu   at HTMLElement.onclick whenever I'm trying to activate/click on the toggle menu button. I legit can't figure out where exactly is the error in the javascript, and addiontionally, I am pretty new to javascript. I'm working on a little website project with the help of HTML, CSS, and JS.

```js
var navLinks = document.getElementById("navLinks");

function showMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "0";
}

function hideMenu() {
  navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7), rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.7)), url(/img/bannerfront.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav img {
  width: 80px;
}

.navLinks {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.navLinks ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navLinks ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.navLinks ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f44336;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navLinks ul li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.text-box {
  width: 90%;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 62px;
}

.text-box p {
  margin: 10px 0 40px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.hero-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none!important;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f44336;
  background: #f44336;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav .far {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width:700px) {
  .text-box h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .navLinks ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .navLinks {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f44336;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
  }
  nav .far {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .navLinks ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">


<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <a href="index2.html"><img src="img/webicon.png" alt=""></a>
    <div class="navLinks">
      <i class="far fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="">COURSE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="far fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
  </nav>

  <div class="text-box">
    <h1> BLAH BLAH BLAH </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque, quod repellat. In at maiores iusto, <br> dolor blanditiis optio rem mollitia fuga, ipsa temporibus beatae. Corrupti est placeat non voluptates impedit.</p>
    <a href="" class="hero-btn"> Visit us to know more </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you do not have an element with the ID `navLinks`. You only have an element with that class. So either change the `class` to an `id` or use `querySelector` or `getElementByClassName`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are misselecting the given **< div class="navLinks" >**

```
<script>
    var navLinks = document.querySelector(".navLinks"); // use this instead!

    function showMenu() {
        navLinks.style.right = "0";
    }

    function hideMenu() {
        navLinks.style.right = "-200px";
    }
  </script>
```